# CustomView with subviews does not calculate the height of the children of a recyclerview correctly

Tags: android

I am probably missing something:

I wanted to write a custom view that has subviews

the idea is to have an outer frame and the inner contents is constantly changing.

When my view has exactly 1 child (that is not a recyclerview) everything is fine.
However, when I add a multi item recyclerview or more than one child, their height is not calculated correctly.

This is my view:

```
class CustomDialog @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, //
                                         attrs: AttributeSet? = null, //
                                         defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : //
    ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

private val contentLayout: ViewGroup?

init {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customview_custom_dialog, this, true)
    contentLayout = findViewById(R.id.contentLayout)
}

override fun addView(child: View?) {
    if (contentLayout == null) {
        super.addView(child)
    } else {
        contentLayout.addView(child)
    }
}

override fun addView(child: View?, index: Int) {
    if (contentLayout == null) {
        super.addView(child, index)
    } else {
        contentLayout.addView(child, index)
    }
}

override fun addView(child: View?, width: Int, height: Int) {
    if (contentLayout == null) {
        super.addView(child, width, height)
    } else {
        contentLayout.addView(child, width, height)
    }
}

override fun addView(child: View?, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) {
    if (contentLayout == null) {
        super.addView(child, params)
    } else {
        contentLayout.addView(child, params)
    }
}

override fun addView(child: View?, index: Int, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) {
    if (contentLayout == null) {
        super.addView(child, index, params)
    } else {
        contentLayout.addView(child, index, params)
    }
}

override fun measureChild(child: View?, parentWidthMeasureSpec: Int, parentHeightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    child?.let {

        val lp = child.layoutParams

        val childWidthMeasureSpec: Int
        val childHeightMeasureSpec: Int


        childWidthMeasureSpec =
            getChildMeasureSpec(parentWidthMeasureSpec, leftPaddingOffset + rightPaddingOffset, lp.width)
        val verticalPadding: Int = topPaddingOffset + bottomPaddingOffset
        childHeightMeasureSpec =
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(max(0, MeasureSpec.getSize(parentHeightMeasureSpec) - verticalPadding),
                    MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)

        child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec)
    }
}

override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
    if (contentLayout != null) {
        val children = contentLayout.children
        var prevChildBottom = 0
        children.forEach { child ->
            child.measure(MeasureSpec.AT_MOST, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
            child.layout(left, top, right, bottom)
            prevChildBottom += child.measuredWidth
        }
    }
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
}

override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

    val heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec)
    if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
        return
    }

    if (childCount > 0) {
        val child = getChildAt(0)
        val widthPadding: Int
        val heightPadding: Int
        val lp = child.layoutParams as LayoutParams
        widthPadding = leftPaddingOffset + rightPaddingOffset + lp.leftMargin + lp.rightMargin
        heightPadding = topPaddingOffset + bottomPaddingOffset + lp.topMargin + lp.bottomMargin
        val desiredHeight = measuredHeight - heightPadding
        if (child.measuredHeight < desiredHeight) {
            val childWidthMeasureSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(widthMeasureSpec, widthPadding, lp.width)
            val childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
            child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec)
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the layout of custom dialog:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_popup"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconBackground"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dash_border"
        android:contentDescription="Icon background"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_coinbase"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iconBackground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/iconBackground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/iconBackground"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iconBackground"
        app:tint="@color/transactionIconTintColor" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottomGuide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/startGuide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="22dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/endGuide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="22dp" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:background="#ff00ff"
        tools:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iconBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomGuide"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/endGuide"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/startGuide"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The idea is to have all the content go into the contentLayout
But if i want to add a recyclerview in, it's not working.

Can you tell me what i missing?

Here is an example for an xml view initialization:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.package.main.CustomDialog xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
</com.package.main.CustomDialog>
```

Comment: I think you are getting height/width before it is rendered, When it happens I try to move the code to a public method and the call it with postDelay or you can use "doOnPreDraw" extension function.

Comment: it is being loaded from an xml